# Overiding the default GraphQL sandbox with GraphQL Playground

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-playground

Everytime when I created a graphQL server with `ApolloServer` and `express` when I navigate to http//:localhost:4000/graphql it opens me a sandbox which looks like:

[image]

What i really want to do is to open a graphql playground which looks like this

[image]

The reason i want this playground it's because it allows me to works with `cookies` very eaisly. I was thinking installing this exextion on my chrome browser will help. Unfortunately it did not work. Here is the instance of my  `ApolloSever` with express in code:

```
 const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [HelloResolver, TodoResolver, AuthResolver],
      validate: false,
    }),
  });
  await apolloServer.start();
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });
```

**Please if you know where what i'm missing help. t has been hours sitting here nothing works**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow! After some hours i realized that I was looking for answers at wrong places. I started reading the docs line by line only to found out that the feature i wanted if for  `Apollo Server 2` and I'm using  `Apollo Server 3`. So to solve this I had to go to my  `ApolloServer` instance and add the following under plugins option:

```
...
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from "apollo-server-core";
...
  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    ....
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground({})],
  });
```

Comment: note: I also had to explicitly install `apollo-server-core` for the plugin to be available in node_modules. It doesn't appear to be included in some bundles, for example, `apollo-server-express`